# Linear algebra (Coordinates)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Question:** Find the coordinates of $x=(1,0,0)$ in relation to base

$$B=\{(1,1,1),(-1,1,0),(1,0,-1)\}.$$

**I tried:** $a,b,c\in R$ such that

$$a(1,1,1)+b(-1,1,0)+c(1,0,-1)=(1,0,0)=x$$

but I'm not sure about it.

I know that a Vector in a subspace can be writed like a combination of a base of the subspace because base is what generate the subespace. If $x$ is in subspace generated for $B$, so $x$ is equal a combination of the $B$'s terms $((1,1,1),(-1,1,0),(1,0,-1))$.

Comment: Your start is correct. This one vector equation corresponds to 3 linear equations in a, b and c. Solve for those variables - you are expected to use row reduction I should think.